# While loop runs forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm working on a Rock, Paper, Scissors game, and I have used several functions as a back-end for the program. My issue is that I don't want any other inputs other than R, P, S, Q, r, s, p, q. So I set up a while loop that if input didn't equal those letters, than the loop will continue to run. However, even though i had fulfilled its conditions, the loop will still continue to run.

```
#Main Program
print('Welcome to Rock, Paper, and Scissors. You know the rules already. But, we will play for as long as you want. If you win more rounds, then you survive. If I win though, well... you already know.')
w = input('Choose a weapon(r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors, q for quit)!: ').lower
while w != 'r' or w != 'p' or w != 's' or w != 'q':
    w = input('Choose a weapon(r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors, q for quit)!: ').lower
else:
    if w == 'q':
        record(1)
         sys.exit
    else:
        if game(w):
            memory(w, fingers)
            respond(numrock, numpaper, numscissors)
            hand1(fingers)
```

Comment: You probably meant `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not used the correct form of `lower()` function. Your conditions were also not correct.

> It is always best practice to inform the user for any invalid or
>   incorrect input rather asking again.

You can modify your code as follows for clarity:

```
print('Welcome to Rock, Paper, and Scissors. You know the rules already. But, we will play for as long as you want. If you win more rounds, then you survive. If I win though, well... you already know.')
while True:
    w = input('Choose a weapon(r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors, q for quit)!: ').lower()
    print("W: ", w)
    if w == 'q':
        break
    elif w == 'r' or w == 'p' or w == 's':
        if game(w):
            memory(w, fingers)
            respond(numrock, numpaper, numscissors)
            hand1(fingers)
    else:
        print("Incorrect Option! Please try again.")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Every letter is not r or not p since no letter is both r and p. So your `while` loops can never end.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points here:

First, lower is a function (use brackets). 
Second, you need to use 'and' instead of 'or'. However, you can rewrite it just like below.

```
#Main Program
print('Welcome to Rock, Paper, and Scissors. You know the rules already. 
 But, we will play for as long as you want. If you win more rounds, then you 
 survive. If I win though, well... you already know.')
w = input('Choose a weapon(r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors, q for 
 quit)!: ').lower()
while w not in 'rpsq' or len(w) > 1:
  w = input('Choose a weapon(r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors, q for 
 quit)!: ').lower()
else:
  if w == 'q':
    record(1)
    sys.exit
else:
  if game(w):
    memory(w, fingers)
    respond(numrock, numpaper, numscissors)
    hand1(fingers)
```

Comment: You can avoid the `len` check by changing the condition to `while w not in ('r', 'p', 's', 'q'):` (`tuple`s of constants are cached not unlike `str`), so the cost should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you set up a set() of allowable responses first you could get what you want.

```
>>> aok = set()
>>> for l in "R" "P" "S" "Q":
...     aok.add(l)
...     aok.add(l.lower())
... 
>>> aok
set(['q', 'p', 'S', 'Q', 'P', 's', 'r', 'R'])
```

Then

```
>>> while w not in aok:
...    print("Invalid entry. Please re-try"
...    w = input("Please enter ....")
...
```

[Not 100% sure of this 'input' function, use whatever input function that works for you].

As @David pointed out, if you tack   `.lower()` on to the end of the input function, that simplifies your comparisons.